# Loading file via BCP with |*| delimiter

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I have a file with `|*|` delimiter. In bcp, using `-t|*|` does not work. can we set delimiter with more than 1 character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use -t '|*|' and that will work fine for that delimiter. Single quotes work for multiple character delimiters for both row and field delimiter.

Comment: Thanks this worked fine. Is there a way to append in bcp? Load files into existing table without deleting the current contents of the table? Can't seem to find it in the parameters

Comment: BCP will append by default it doesn't clear the table itself by default. If you want to do something specific you can also use the --initstring option which allows you to execute a piece of Transact-SQL before loading data.

If you have concerns regarding duplicate keys or similar and the data import failing, then BCPing into a staging table instead then doing a merge/update or similar between the two tables may be a better option for you.